# Debug statement in Ansible Playbook behaves differently than in Ansible Role

Tags: ansible

I cannot seem to get an Ansible debug statement in a loop to display the individual item values when running the debug statement in a role. For comparison, given this playbook named ./test.yaml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: test
    debug:
      var: item
    loop:
      - 1
      - 2
```

This command:

```
ansible-playbook test.yaml
```

Produces this result:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****...
TASK [test] ****...
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "item": 1
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
   "item": 2
}
```

But given this file: ./roles/TestRole/tasks/main.yaml:

```
- name: test
  debug:
    var: item
  loop:
    - 1
    - 2
```

This command:

```
ansible localhost -m include_role -a name=TestRole
```

Produces this result:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "include_variables": {
        "name": "FooRole"
    }
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg" "All items completed"
}
```

So - rather than displaying the item values, the debug statement in the role just says "All items completed". It looks like looped debug statements in roles behave differently than looped debug statements in playbooks. Am I doing something wrong? Running Ansible 2.7.9 on python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively what you get from the adhoc command (and I have absolutely no clue why). Meanwhile this is a rather edge case of using it. You would rather include a role in a playbook. Both playbook examples below will give you the result you are expecting:

## Classic role execution

```
---
- name: test1 for role
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - role: TestRole
```

## Include role

```
---
- name: test2 for roles
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: include role
      include_role:
        name: TestRole
```

Comment: Well - this is a case where a role is included in a playbook (I omitted that for clarity) but the included role itself has to handle multiple items. The look executes and the items appear to be handled, it's just the debug statement that seems to act differently...